# What is #define UIKIT_STRING_ENUMS ？

Tags: ios, objective-c

the code:

```
<UIKit/UIApplication.h> line 293-297
 #if UIKIT_STRING_ENUMS
 typedef NSString * UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey  NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM;
 #else
 typedef NSString * UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey;
 #endif


<UIKit/UIKitDefines.h>
 #define UIKIT_STRING_ENUMS ((defined(SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_UIKIT_EPOCH) && SWIFT_SDK_OVERLAY_UIKIT_EPOCH >= 2))
```

What is #define  UIKIT_STRING_ENUMS ？

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://academy.realm.io/posts/altconf-nikita-lutsenko-objc-swift-interoperability/) page.

Answer (score 1):

`UIKIT_STRING_ENUMS` is a macro to control how Objective-C code is imported into Swift